# Highcharts - Performance issue using chart with x values date and TIME

Tags: highcharts

I am plotting a chart with ‘y’ axis being numeric values and ‘x’ axis being date time values.
I was able to process a JSON object of 3000 items. However, because of our business rules, we also need to display the time: hours + minutes in the chart’s tooltips.

This changed everything!

Now the chart takes about 15 seconds to plot 2000 records. This is unacceptable.

I can see clearly that when I remove the time part of my Date object the charts works perfectly. It is just when added the hours and minutes that performance gets affected.

Trying different things I realized that your charts should support the amount of data I am using since it is not massive.

We love the charts but performance is key for us to continue using your products.
Can you help me with this issue?

Please check this fiddle so you can understand my problem. Feel free to remove the hours and minutes variables from the DateUtc creation:

https://jsfiddle.net/17a3jry9/7/

Thanks in advance!

```
var pointStart = new Date();

var data = [{"date":"2017-11-08","time":"1712","perc":10},{"date":"2017-11-08","time":"1608","perc":10},{"date":"2017-11-08","time":"1506","perc":10},{"date":"2017-11-08","time":"1408","perc":10},{"date":"2017-11-08","time":"1309","perc":10},{"date":"2017-11-08","time":"1207","perc":10},{"date":"2017-11-08","time":"1110","perc":10},{"date":"2017-11-08","time":"1003","perc":10},{"date":"2017-11-08","time":"0910","perc":10},{"date":"2017-11-08","time":"0810","perc":10},{"date":"2017-11-08","time":"0708","perc":10},{"date":"2017-11-09","time":"1710","perc":10},{"date":"2017-11-09","time":"1604","perc":10},{"date":"2017-11-09","time":"1510","perc":10},{"date":"2017-11-09","time":"1406","perc":10},{"date":"2017-11-09","time":"1310","perc":10},{"date":"2017-11-09","time":"1205","perc":10},{"date":"2017-11-09","time":"1107","perc":10},{"date":"2017-11-09","time":"1010","perc":10},{"date":"2017-11-09","time":"0912","perc":10},{"date":"2017-11-09","time":"0806","perc":10}{"date":"2018-10-25","time":"0709","perc":10},{"date":"2018-10-25","time":"1009","perc":10},{"date":"2018-10-25","time":"1208","perc":10},{"date":"2018-10-25","time":"1309","perc":10},{"date":"2018-10-25","time":"1410","perc":10},{"date":"2018-10-25","time":"1510","perc":10},{"date":"2018-10-25","time":"1702","perc":10},{"date":"2018-10-26","time":"1409","perc":10},{"date":"2018-10-26","time":"0710","perc":10},{"date":"2018-10-26","time":"1505","perc":10},{"date":"2018-10-26","time":"1704","perc":10},{"date":"2018-10-29","time":"0708","perc":10},{"date":"2018-10-29","time":"1007","perc":10},{"date":"2018-10-29","time":"1208","perc":10},{"date":"2018-10-29","time":"1406","perc":10},{"date":"2018-10-29","time":"1509","perc":10},{"date":"2018-10-29","time":"1610","perc":10},{"date":"2018-10-30","time":"0710","perc":10},{"date":"2018-10-30","time":"1010","perc":10},{"date":"2018-10-30","time":"1207","perc":10},{"date":"2018-10-30","time":"1409","perc":10},{"date":"2018-10-30","time":"1510","perc":10},{"date":"2018-10-30","time":"1709","perc":10},{"date":"2018-10-31","time":"0708","perc":10},{"date":"2018-10-31","time":"1009","perc":10},{"date":"2018-10-31","time":"1206","perc":10},{"date":"2018-10-31","time":"1409","perc":10},{"date":"2018-10-31","time":"1509","perc":10},{"date":"2018-10-31","time":"1708","perc":10},{"date":"2018-11-01","time":"0707","perc":10},{"date":"2018-11-01","time":"1007","perc":10},{"date":"2018-11-01","time":"1108","perc":10},{"date":"2018-11-01","time":"1250","perc":10},{"date":"2018-11-01","time":"1509","perc":10},{"date":"2018-11-01","time":"1407","perc":10},{"date":"2018-11-01","time":"1709","perc":10},{"date":"2018-11-02","time":"0708","perc":10},{"date":"2018-11-02","time":"1007","perc":10},{"date":"2018-11-02","time":"1108","perc":10},{"date":"2018-11-02","time":"1210","perc":10},{"date":"2018-11-02","time":"1407","perc":10},{"date":"2018-11-02","time":"1509","perc":10},{"date":"2018-11-02","time":"1608","perc":10},{"date":"2018-11-02","time":"1715","perc":10},{"date":"2018-11-05","time":"0707","perc":10},{"date":"2018-11-05","time":"1007","perc":10},{"date":"2018-11-05","time":"1209","perc":10},{"date":"2018-11-05","time":"1408","perc":10},{"date":"2018-11-05","time":"1509","perc":10},{"date":"2018-11-05","time":"1611","perc":10},{"date":"2018-11-05","time":"1715","perc":10},{"date":"2018-11-06","time":"0708","perc":10},{"date":"2018-11-06","time":"1007","perc":10},{"date":"2018-11-06","time":"1201","perc":10},{"date":"2018-11-06","time":"1410","perc":10},{"date":"2018-11-06","time":"1510","perc":10},{"date":"2018-11-06","time":"1709","perc":10},{"date":"2018-11-07","time":"0708","perc":10},{"date":"2018-11-07","time":"1007","perc":10},{"date":"2018-11-07","time":"1209","perc":10},{"date":"2018-11-07","time":"1307","perc":10},{"date":"2018-11-07","time":"1410","perc":10},{"date":"2018-11-07","time":"1506","perc":10},{"date":"2018-11-07","time":"1708","perc":10},{"date":"2018-11-08","time":"0707","perc":10},{"date":"2018-11-08","time":"1009","perc":10},{"date":"2018-11-08","time":"1207","perc":10},{"date":"2018-11-08","time":"1309","perc":10},{"date":"2018-11-08","time":"1412","perc":10},{"date":"2018-11-08","time":"1508","perc":10}];


var newSeries = data.map(function (key) {

  var utilDate = new Date(key.date);
  var hours = parseInt(key.time.slice(0, 2));
  var minutes = parseInt(key.time.slice(2, 4));

  return { x: Date.UTC(utilDate.getFullYear(), utilDate.getMonth(), utilDate.getDate(), hours, minutes), y: key.perc, key: key.id };

});  

Highcharts.stockChart('container', {

  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    title: {
      text: 'Date'
    }
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Util (%)'
    },
    min: 0
  },
  tooltip: {

    headerFormat: '<b>{point.x: %A, %b %e, %I:%M %p}</b><br>'
    //pointFormat: '{point.x:%e. %b}: {point.y:.2f} m'
  },

  colors: ['teal', 'red'],

  // Define the data points. All series have a dummy year
  // of 1970/71 in order to be compared on the same x axis. Note
  // that in JavaScript, months start at 0 for January, 1 for February etc.
  series: [{
    name: "Util",
    data: newSeries
  }],

  title: {
    text: 'Util Movement'
  },

  subtitle: {
    text: ""
  },

  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      cursor: 'pointer',
      turboThreshold: 10000,
      point: {
        events: {

        }
      },
      label: {
        connectorAllowed: false
      },
      pointStart: pointStart.getFullYear()
    }
  },

  responsive: {
    rules: [{
      condition: {
        maxWidth: 200
      },
      chartOptions: {
        legend: {
          layout: 'horizontal',
          align: 'center',
          verticalAlign: 'bottom'
        }
      }
    }]
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look to the browser console, you have information there about error: `Highcharts error #15: www.highcharts.com/errors/15`.

This means that you have unsorted data, so you need to sort them:

```
newSeries.sort(function(a, b){
    return a.x - b.x
});
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/onq0Lurx/

Comment: Yes, this was the cause. Thank you very much!